# Why won't my program read from a USB interrupt endpoint

Tags: linux, usb, driver, interrupt, libusb

I am writing a libusb program to interact with a USB gamepad. I found it, opened it, detached from kernel, claimed interface, and when I try to usb_interrupt_read it returns -110 (resource temporarily unavailable)
what is doing on?

Also, usb_set_configuration fails, so I commented it out. Do I need it?

Why isn't it reading?

```
i = usb_interrupt_read(handle, 0x81, bytes, 8, 50);
printf("%d read\n", i);
perror("read");
```

Comment: If you didn't call `usb_set_configuration()`, how do you know the current configuration *has* an interrupt endpoint? Can you give some more information about that failure?

Comment: I tried set configuration, but read still fails.  the game pad has just one configuration, one interface, one altsetting, and

Comment: endpoints. 0x02 and 0x81. read returns -110.

Comment: I know that from the USB tree in Linux. what do you need t know about the failure? make I can give you more so you can give me more...

Comment: It sounds like you are using a very old version of libusb.  You should try [libusb 1.0.x](http://libusb.info/) and its `libusb_interrupt_transfer` function.